# How to delete dynamically created datagridview columns in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, datagridview

Im unable to delete columns that i had created during run time. How do I delete dynamically created columns?

Here is the code to create columns in a button :

```
           //creating new column
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            column1.ReadOnly = false;
            column1.Name = "column"+ incrementcount;
            column1.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            //column1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
            column1.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            column1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            column1.HeaderText = "Column" + incrementcount;                
            column1.Width = 100;
            dataGridView4.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView4.Columns.Add(column1);
```

And im trying to delete the column like this, I also tried to hide the column :

```
           // dataGridView4.Columns[poss].Visible = false;
           dataGridView4.Columns.Remove(dataGridView4.Columns[positionindex].HeaderText);
           dataGridView4.Refresh();
```

But still the columns are visible. How do I delete it?

Comment: try change `.HeaderText` to `.Name`?

Comment: Tried that, column still visible.

Comment: please update with `tried` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use:

- Visibility flag to disable the column
- Use the DataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(YourIndex)

To get the index of a column use:

```
DataGridView.Columns["YourColumn"].Index;
```

Comment: I had tried RemoveAt(index) but it didnt work before. After looking at your reply I tried again and found out that the index number i was supplying it was wrong. Now it works.

Comment: Perfect! Nice 